# How to pass an extra parameter to Vision framework?

Tags: swift, coreml, apple-vision

I have a Swift / CoreML code that works fine. I want to simplify my code by using the Vision framework.
In this code, there is a UIImage -> CGImage -> CVPixelBuffer conversion that I would like to get rid of. I know that using Vision one can pass directly a CGImage as input parameter. The problem I have is that my model takes 2 inputs (image + MLMultiArray) and output and image:

```
Inputs

    my_input : Image (Color 512 x 512)
    my_sigma : MultiArray (Float32 1)

Outputs

    my_output : Image (Color 512 x 512)
```

I've tried to pass the sigma parameter as follow:

```swift
guard let cgImage = uiImage.cgImage else {
    return nil
}

let options:[VNImageOption: Any] = [VNImageOption(rawValue: "my_sigma"): 0.1]

let handler = VNImageRequestHandler(cgImage: cgImage, options: options)
do {
    try handler.perform(visionRequest)
} catch {
    print(error)
}
```

By doing so, I get the following error:

*[coreml] Failure verifying inputs. no results:Error Domain=com.apple.vis Code=3 "The VNCoreMLTransform request failed" UserInfo={NSLocalizedDescription=The VNCoreMLTransform request failed, NSUnderlyingError=0x280cbbab0 {Error Domain=com.apple.CoreML Code=0 "Required input feature not passed to neural network."*

So, it seems that I didn't pass correctly the second parameter to the request handler. I have not been able to find the answer.

- What is the correct way to pass such a parameter to Vision?
- Do you know if I can use Vision to output an image directly?

Thank you for you help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have a look at the `featureProvider` property of `VNCoreMLRequest`. This is an object that provides additional inputs, i.e. anything other than the image input.

Comment: Following your advice, I'll answer my own question by showing what worked for this very example. Thanks for your suggestion.

Comment: I probably should have mentioned the existence of `MLDictionaryFeatureProvider` but your code looks fine too.

Comment: You're right, the following code seems to do the trick:
`let array = try! MLMultiArray(shape: [1], dataType: .float32);
array[0] = NSNumber(value: self.sigma);
visionModel.featureProvider = try? MLDictionaryFeatureProvider(dictionary: ["my_sigma": array])`

Comment: I think you don't even need the MLMultiArray, i.e. try using `MLDictionaryFeatureProvider(dictionary: ["my_sigma": 3.14])`.

Comment: Currently, it's needed: _Failure verifying inputs.
Error while performing Vision request: Error Domain=com.apple.vis Code=3 "The VNCoreMLTransform request failed" UserInfo={NSLocalizedDescription=The VNCoreMLTransform request failed, NSUnderlyingError=0x28350b570 {Error Domain=com.apple.CoreML Code=1 "MultiArrayConstraint only allows MultiArrays" UserInfo={NSLocalizedDescription=MultiArrayConstraint only allows MultiArrays}}}_

Answer (score 1):

The code I provide bellow seems to be working fine. It might not be optimal, but at least it works which is a good first step. The main difficulty was to understand how the `MLFeatureProvider` works:

```swift
class SigmaProvider: MLFeatureProvider {

    let sigma: Double

    init(sigma: Double) {
        self.sigma = sigma
    }

    var featureNames: Set<String> {
        get {
            return ["my_sigma"]
        }
    }

    func featureValue(for featureName: String) -> MLFeatureValue? {
        if (featureName == "my_sigma") {
            let array = try! MLMultiArray(shape: [1], dataType: .float32)
            array[0] = NSNumber(value: self.sigma)
            return MLFeatureValue(multiArray: array)
        }
        return nil
    }
}
```

This class defines an input named `my_sigma` and of type `MLMultiArray`. Bellow is the code that applies the CoreML model (named `model`) to an input UIImage:

```swift
// Input CGImage
guard let cgImage = uiImage.cgImage else {
    return nil
}

// Load and setup the Vision model
guard let visionModel = try? VNCoreMLModel(for: model.model) else {
    fatalError("Cannot load Vision ML model")
}
visionModel.inputImageFeatureName = "my_input"
visionModel.featureProvider = SigmaProvider(sigma: self.sigma)

// Create the request
let request = VNCoreMLRequest(model: visionModel)
request.usesCPUOnly = false

// Handler
let handler = VNImageRequestHandler(cgImage: cgImage)

// Process
do {
    try handler.perform([request])
}
catch {
    print("Error while performing Vision request: \(error)")
    return nil
}

// Get the result
guard let results = request.results else {
    print("No request results")
    return nil
}

// Convert the resulting CVPixelBuffer into a UIImage
for case let resultingImage as VNPixelBufferObservation in results {
    if resultingImage.featureName == "my_output" {
        let ciOutput = CIImage(cvPixelBuffer: resultingImage.pixelBuffer)
        UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(uiImage.size, true, 1.0)
        UIImage(ciImage: ciOutput).draw(at: CGPoint(x: 0, y: 0))
        let output = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext()
        UIGraphicsEndImageContext()
        return output
    }
}
```

Note that the first argument of my model, `my_input`, is not needed in the `SigmaProvider` class. It is specified using the `inputImageFeatureName` property. Finally, I access the `my_output` by iterating through all results.

I hope this will help someone.